# php delete array index where index > [number]

Tags: php

I have an array like this

```
[
'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'
]
```

I want to delete the array elements where `index>5` 
after doing that I must have this array

```
[
'a','b','c','d','e'
]
```

thanks for your help 
and excuse me for my grammar, my native language is not english

Comment: Try using [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few ways of doing it. [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)() is an easy one.

```
$array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'];
//The array;

$start = 0;
//At which element to start

$length = 5;
//How many elements to include

$shortened_array = array_slice($array, $start, $length);
//array_slice is your friend

var_dump($shortened_array);

/**
Will return:

array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "d"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "e"
}

*/
```